# More same row in SQL

Tags: sql

How do I call the row it belongs to again according to the data in the table in SQL? For example, if the AMOUNT is 4 in a row, I want to print that same row 4 times.

I can't anything. Can you help me?

Comment: Use a recursive cte.

Comment: Join to a tally table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic example of how you can accomplish is as follows.

First create a [tally table](http://perspective.altervista.org/index.php/resources/sql-server/30-tally-table)

```
Create table Numbers (n int not null);
insert into Numbers values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
```

Then join with your query equating, in this case, `Amount` with the required number of rows

```
/* Your table */
create table t(Id int, Amount int)
insert into t values (1, 2),(2, 4);

select t.* 
from t
join Numbers n on n.n <= t.Amount;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot your comment. So how ı can do this two joinned tables? Do you know?

Comment: Simply add the numbers table join to the existing query using the appropriate criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear actually, but as I understand you can use that PL/SQL too, and @Stu's answer is so suitable.

```
declare
cursor cur is select amount from your_tab;
begin
  for j in cur
    loop
    for i in 1..j.amount loop
      dbms_output.put_line('Amount is ' || to_char(j.amount) || ' and it printed ' || to_char(j.amount) || ' time(s).');
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
```